# В чем ошибка в моем коде?

Tags: c++

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;



bool summa(int);
bool swap(int);
bool bubbleSort(int);
bool printArray(int);


  int main ()
  {
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "rus");
    int Random_list1[10]
    {
    };
    int Random_list2[10]
    {
    };


    srand (time (NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
    Random_list1[i] = rand () % 410 - 200;
    Random_list2[i] = rand () % 410 - 200;

      }

    bubbleSort(Random_list1,10);
    bubbleSort(Random_list2,10);
    printArray(Random_list1,10);
    printArray(Random_list2,10); 

    if (Random_list1[0] == Random_list2[0]){
        cout << "Наименьшие элементы массивов равны" << endl;

    }else if (Random_list1[0]<Random_list2[0]){
        cout << "Сумма положительных элементов массива 1"<<endl ;
        summa(Random_list1,10); 
    }else {
        cout << "Сумма положительных элементов массива 2" << endl;
        summa(Random_list2,10);
    }
  }

  void 
summa(int arr[],int n)
{
    int i,s=0;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
       if (arr[i]>0)
        s = s+arr[i];


    }
    cout<<s<<endl;

}
void
swap (int *xp, int *yp)
{
  int temp = *xp;
  *xp = *yp;
  *yp = temp;
}


void
bubbleSort (int arr[], int n)
{
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)


    for (j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
      if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
    swap (&arr[j], &arr[j + 1]);

}

void printArray(int arr[], int size) 
{ 
    int i; 
    for (i=0; i < size; i++) 
        printf("%d ", arr[i]); 
    printf("\n"); 
}



main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:36:31: error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
     bubbleSort(Random_list1,10);
```

Comment: Дополни вопрос содержанием ошибки

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У Вас прототипы функций не соответствуют фактическому определению.

Прототипы:

```
bool summa(int);
bool swap(int);
bool bubbleSort(int);
bool printArray(int);
```

А по факту:

```
void summa(int arr[], int n)
void swap(int *xp, int *yp)
void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n)
void printArray(int arr[], int size)
```